# Debug and Release issue in iOS application

Tags: ios

I have created an iOS application where I am having different server base `URL` for **Release and Debug**.

If I run the application using `Ad-hoc profile` which base `URL` it will take **Release OR Debug**.

I have added `URL` in the key-value format in `Build Setting` -  `User-Defined` and I am fetching it in the application.

Comment: In my experience, I've used different xcschemes for different servers, and based on what scheme I'm using I'm fetching from a different config file that is setup via a build time compile script.

Answer (score 0):

Base URL is the one you define in your project it has got nothing to do with your build settings. 
Mostly we use Production or Release Base URL when opting for Release and Dev Base URL is used when opting for Debug mode.